# R - Read a file with a column who contains a string with commas

Tags: r

I trying to read a file that contains a column with a string with comma, somehting like this:

```
Input <- "A, B, C
1.76, 1%, yei, yei
2.00, 2%, foo
3.000, 3% , foo"
```

Where:  yei, yei is the value of colum C:

```
A      B        C
1.76   1%   yei, yei
2.00   2%      test
3.000  3%      foo
```

I thought that maybe a conversion function works, is possible to deal with this case in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `read.table`

```
Input <- read.table(text="A, B, C
1.76, 1%, 'yei, yei'
2.00, 2%, foo
3.000, 3% , foo", sep=",", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

Input
#    A  B        C
#1 1.76 1% yei, yei
#2 2.00 2%      foo
#3 3.00 3%      foo
```

#### Update

If there are no quotes for 'yei, yei', we can create one with `sub` after reading with `readLines`

```
Input <- readLines(textConnection("A, B, C
1.76, 1%, yei, yei
2.00, 2%, foo
3.000, 3% , foo"))

 read.table(text=sub("(([^,]+,){2})\\s+(.*)", "\\1'\\3'", Input), 
             header=TRUE, sep=",", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
 #     A    B        C
 #1 1.76   1% yei, yei
 #2 2.00   2%      foo
 #3 3.00  3%       foo
```

Comment: But the problem is that in the file,  'yei, yei' don't have quotation marks, the first row is only something like: "1.76, 1%, yei, yei", or I need to preproccess the file?

Comment: Thanks, a doubt what's the meaning of "\\1'\\3'"?

Comment: @bluepill5  In the `sub`, we match some pattern and place it in a capture group (`(....)`), the backreference of that capture group is `\\1`, `\\3`.  In this case, the first capture group is `([^,]+,){2}`, and the second one is just a wrapping bracket over the first one which we don't need and the 3rd is `(.*)`

Comment: And for example which would change with: `Input <- readLines(textConnection("tipt,ope,fe,tit,sor,imp
PMN,V,28/06/2007,CF,BI,S.A,10000"))`, where the problem is with 'BI, S.A', thanks @akrun

Answer (score 1):

```
A <- c(1.76, 2.00, 3.000)
B <- c("1%", "2%", "3%")
C <- c("yei, yei", "foo", "foo")

as.data.frame(cbind(A,B,C))

#     A  B        C
#1 1.76 1% yei, yei
#2    2 2%      foo
#3    3 3%      foo
```